# Android Studio - location for SDK and Project Files in SSD

Tags: ssd, permission, android

I have a SSD and a HDD, wherein the SSD is a bootable drive. I have moved the `/user`folder to a partition on HDD wherein it is working perfectly. The Android SDK and projects are also on Hard disk at the moment.

I want to move the SDK and projects to SSD too, since I will get better execution times. But I don't know where to place the files now since the `/user` folder is now residing on HDD. I tried moving the SDK and projects to `/` but then Android Studio was not able to open the files due to permission issues. Any idea what permissions to give the folders or where to store the files on SSD?

**Update :-**

Running on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2

Permission for folder on SSD root(`/`)

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 14 RohanKandwal  wheel   448 Dec 27 12:53 Android Projects
drwxrwxrwx+ 19 RohanKandwal  admin   608 Dec 27 15:16 SDK
```

Permission for folder on HDD

```
drwxr-xr-x   17 RohanKandwal  admin        578 Dec  1 11:20 Android Projects
drwxr-xr-x@  20 RohanKandwal  admin        680 Dec 27 15:46 SDK
```

Comment: @Allan Sorry, didn't mention explicitly, yes this is on a mac. If I run Android Studio directly then the projects are not opening with log showing permission denied.

Comment: @Allan Usually I would have added the files to the user directory but since the user directory is now in HDD, I don't know where to place them.

Comment: @Allan Used a tutorial similar to https://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/relocate-the-home-folder-to-another-drive-or-volume--mac-48822 . The /user folder now resides on HDD.

Comment: So.....why not follow the instructions to relocate the folder *back* to the boot volume?  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Allan Don't want to move the entire folder back since usually these folders contains documents, videos, etc which is a waste of space on SSD. Just want to have the SDK and projects on SSD for faster access, rest remains as is, something I can do for this?

Comment: @Allan Updated the question with required information, thanks for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70853/discussion-between-rohan-kandwal-and-allan).

Comment: @Allan Continuing in chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed following settings on my mac -

1. The `Users` folder, which usually contains documents, videos, audios, etc are not to be stored on SSD but on HDD.
2. The `Android` folder, which contains the Android SDK and Android Projects, to be contained on SSD since it will improve Android studio performance.

Since I was not able to do it by just changing the permissions on my mac, here's what I did -

1. Create a new [APFS Volume](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208033) on SSD from Disk Utility.
2. Move the Android Folder on the new APFS Volume.

Above fit perfectly to my needs and does not require any further change, so I am marking this as my answer.